# Traveling only with first and last name (instead of full name)

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration

Okay this is a bit complicated if you're not chinese. But I will appreciate any help I can get so please take the time to read.

My chinese name is being left out of my e-ticket and I'm afraid that I might be denied entry.

E.g.

My name in passport: Mary (english name/first name) CHAN (last name/surname) Li Min (chinese name). 
Name reflected on e-ticket: Mary CHAN.

The airlines is super unhelpful so I'm really annoyed. Will this be a problem for me? I read in many forums that as long as your first and last name is fine, it shouldn't be a problem.

And to think that initially I wanted to leave the airport because the layover time is 12 hours. I better just stay put.

Comment: In the title you said "first and last", in the example you mentioned it was more like first and middle names. Please fix either the title or the example to reflect the real situation you are facing.

Comment: Plus, the "share your experience" part is totally off-topic here, what is it exactly that you are looking for? will this cause a problem to you? or how to fix it? asking people to share experiences can not be a question..

Comment: Sorry, made the corrections. Hope it sounds clearer now.

Comment: it's important to know the country of your passport, you write you are Chinese, but passports from PRC, HK, Macao or Taiwan are completely different

Comment: Hi Guido, I hold a Singapore passport.

Comment: Where is the connecting flight...?

Answer (score 3):

Your name should appear on the ticket exactly as it's in the passport. To make it simpler:

First name on the ticket = first name on passport

Last name on ticket = last name on passport

it doesn't matter what is your english name or your nick name, what matters is what is written on the passport in english.

So, here's an example of a Chinese passport (I just googled) so the name should be WANG WENYI on the ticket. Remember that the airline employee at the counter or the security guy at the checkpoint just want to see that it fits.

To be on the safe side (since I'm picky) call the airline and request to know whether or not your Chinese name (in the passport below JILIN) should appear on the ticket. Every call you make to the airlines - make sure they document it in the PNR (just in case something goes wrong).

[image]

Comment: The problem I find is that, passports such as the one in the image, only has one field for Name, while airlines will ask for First Name and Last Name.  If your passport name is A B C (first middle last) it is ambiguous whether you need to put First name is A or A B